# Chrome: Setting width on inline-block element programatically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a number of tiled containers (div's with inline-block) that represent tables

[] [] []

When I change the width on one of these containers, Chrome is failing to 'rerender' them and the table now spills over one another.  (This only occurs in chrome)

[ []] []

```
// Updates each container with the correct HTML and the appropriate width values
function UpdateContainer(crosstab)
{
    var container = $(".GeneratedTableContainer").filter("[index='" + crosstab.Index + "']").find(".GeneratedTableContent");
    container.html(crosstab.Html);

    // Capture the width of the table and update the .GeneratedTableContainer and .GeneratedTableWrapper to prevent overflow.
    var width = container.find(".Crosstab").css("width");
    container.closest(".GeneratedTableContainer").css("width", width);
    container.closest(".GeneratedTableWrapper").css("width", width);
}



div.GeneratedTableWrapper
{

display: inline-block;
min-width: 500px;
width: auto;
margin-left: 5px;
}

div.GeneratedTableContainer
{
margin-top: 5px;
min-width: 500px;
width: auto;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
bottom:5px;
}
```

Is there a way to force chrome to rerender the container?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a class to the container

```
$(".GeneratedTableWrapper").AddClass("Resized")
```

Chrome knows to rerender those containers thus preventing the overlap.